# SonarQube Quality Profiles leads to "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Tags: sonarqube

I've downloaded a SonarQube 4.2 and analyzed a project locally. After that, everytime I clicked "Quality Profiles" I got "We're sorry, but something went wrong.", even though the settings on the project itself show three profiles to be present already. Because I always pick the version with the bugs when downloading, I tried the same thing with a fresh SonarQube 4.2, 4.1.2, 4.0 and Sonar 3.7.4. Out of the box all of them presented the same page, so I guess this meaningless error message is by default. I already searched the doc and Google but couldn't find anyone explaining what I need to do to get the profiles to show correctly. So what did I miss?

Comment: I'm sure that you use Java8. Right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. So what's the solution? Switch back to Java7?

Comment: Java8 is not supported (yet) as runtime environment. Note that SonarQube 4.2 allows to analyze Java8 code, but not to run analyzers with Java8.

Comment: Typically. I had to delete Java8 entirely, because neither setting the PATH variable nor the system preferences made it go away, but now it works. Thanks!

Comment: You can now upgrade to sonar 4.3 http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5191

Comment: Nice Simon & neferlio, removing Java 8 solved this.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change your java version. Sonar 3.4.7 (which is the latest stable version) runs correctly with java 7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You have install jre o jdk 7 and edit wrapper.conf inside conf dir:

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# JVM
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\java
```